# Not every signal gets handled in c

Tags: c, unix, signals

I have a little c program where I'm creating 3 child processes using fork:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int signum) {
    printf("SIGNAL ARRIVED\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t parent = getpid();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
        kill(parent, SIGTERM);
        exit(0);
    }
}
    while(wait(NULL) > 0) {}
    exit(0);
}
```

My expected output is three `SIGNAL ARRIVED`, but sometimes I only get two of them.
Why is this, what am I missing, and how can I achieve to get every time three?

Comment: Signals are delivered asynchronously, there is no guarantee that they will be delivered before the signalling process terminates. If you need to guarantee your parent process actually sees and handles all three signals you might try synchronous signal handling. See signal(7) for details: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: Wrong code. Read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) & [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: @ChrisDodd points out that regular signals are not queued either, which is another possible source of error. Linux supports so-called "real-time signals" which are queueable. See the above signal man page for details.

Comment: why are you sending a signal, let alone SIGTERM? there is a rather rich set of IPCs for use (the list is available in your favourite unix/linux programming book)

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam and I need to know how signals behave, that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals are not queued, they are just flags.  Sending a signal to a process just sets the flag, and if the flag is already set, it has no additional effect.  So if multiple signals are sent to a process before it notices them and runs the signal handler and clears the flag, some will seem to be "lost"